# Multiple value checking with swifts guard statement?

Tags: ios, swift

Most of my searching here on SO is proving futile. My guard statement works as far as checking each value and correcting it if one is nil. However if two of the values are nil, then I crash unexpectedly finding nil while unwrapping an optional. How does one go about checking that multiple values are not nil using swifts guard statement?

```
    func protectInput() {

    guard Double(myAmount.text!) != nil else {
        myAmount.text = "0.00"
        return
    }

    guard Double(myRate.text!) != nil else {
        myRate.text = "0.00"
        return
    }

    guard Double(myFee.text!) != nil else {
        myFee.text = "0.00"
        return
    }
}
```

Maybe I am completely on the wrong track, any help with an example would be appreciated. I have read all I can take in. I do not need to compare two values or have some complex comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guard statements aren't the right thing to use here. If any of them fail, then you will return from the function and your later statements won't get executed. So if myAmount doesn't have a valid value in it, you'll never correct myRate and myFee.

```
if Double(myAmount.text ?? "") == nil {
    myAmount.text = "0.00"
}
```

This pattern would suit you better:

- the text value isn't force unwrapped any more, which will prevent one potential crash - `??` is the nil coalescing operator which will use either the text value or, in this case, an empty string
- there is no return so the function will check all of the values.

Comment: Thank you it solved the actual question. Since this works when two values are nil why would it not work when three are nil? Its a new question yes but for understanding purposes...

Comment: You weren't clear where the crash is happening - I assumed it was somewhere else which depended on the values you were adjusting here.

Comment: If you're not sure where or why your crash is happening then add an exception breakpoint which will stop you on the exact line, that helps a lot with debugging.

Comment: I am absolutely sure its happening here. This isn't a very complex situation, except for my level of knowledge with coding. I have 5 fields, 2 are not enabled for input. One nil value and it adjusts, Two nil and it adjusts now. 3 nil and It crashes. Basically A + C * B. As you've answered the actual question thank you. I will dive deeper into figuring this out in the morning.

Comment: If it's always when checking a specific field then there's something about that field that is different. It's nothing to do with how many guard statements you have.